# Pushing Arithmetic sequence into an array in the cleanest syntax - Javascript

Tags: javascript

so it's not much of a problem, but I really like all the array methods in JS like array.map, .reduce etc..
And I encountered this problem, which I need to build an Arithmetic Sequence parameters(first number, the common differnce and total numbers) so it looks like this:

```
let number = 3;
let d = 5;
let N = 6;
```

so they way I solved it it is just pushing it into an arrary, but I wondered is there more clean way to do it using one of the array methods? I really tried to figure out but couldn't.
This is my solution:

```
let number = 3;
let d = 5;
let N = 6;
 for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    arr.push(number);
    number += d;
}
console.log(arr);
// 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28
```

I would be happy to know if there's cleaner way to make this simple action. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> is there more clean way to do it using one of the array methods?

Not really! You *can* use them, e.g. `Array.from` with a function that maps 0..n to the corresponding value in the sequence:

```js
Array.from({length: N}, (_, i) => 3 + 5 * i)
```

but you don’t *have* to, and I think your original is nice and readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and supply the mapping function as second parameter.

Since you have your starting number (`number`), difference (`d`) and length (`N`), then it's trivial to express this as a mapping function by introducing `n` as the *current* step, which will follow the normal formula of `a + nd` :

```
const arithmeticSequenceMember = (number, d, n) => number + n*d
```

Now to generate the entire series:

```js
const arithmeticSequenceMember = (number, d, n) => number + n*d

const generateAritmeticSequence = (number, d, N) =>
  Array.from({length: N}, (_, n) => arithmeticSequenceMember(number, d, n));
  
console.log(generateAritmeticSequence(3, 5, 6))
```

You can also create a generator function that will create unbounded arithmetic sequences. You can then decide how many you want and only get that sequence:

```js
const arithmeticSequenceMember = (number, d, n) => number + n*d

function* aritmeticSequenceGenerator(number, d) {
  let i = 0;
  while(true) {
    yield arithmeticSequenceMember(number, d, i++);
  }
}

const gen1 = aritmeticSequenceGenerator(3, 5);

console.log(gen1.next().value); // 1
console.log(gen1.next().value); // 2
console.log(gen1.next().value); // 3
console.log(gen1.next().value); // 4
console.log(gen1.next().value); // 5
console.log(gen1.next().value); // 6

const gen2 = aritmeticSequenceGenerator(3, 5);
console.log(Array.from({length: 6}, () => gen2.next().value)); // [1-6]
```

Comment: Hopefully `gen1.take(5)` works soon (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers/blob/master/README.md) ...

Comment: @JonasWilms here's hoping. I've been thinking of making my own little helper here like this so you could, say, do a `.filter` on an iterable. But then again, I never really use iterators enough for this.